# Is it possible to make a style sheet for Safari's Top Site page?

Tags: macos, safari, formatting

Mavericks : is it possible to use a style sheet for Safari's Top Sites page?

Are there style sheet examples to draw from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Chrome, Safari doesn't seems to use a webpage for the top sites but rather another programmatic view.

As you might have seen, the webinspector doesn't work on this page.

Comment: Yep, I did notice that I could not invoke the inspector.. Too bad.. Radar!?